# i want navigate to another file in webview.

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

i want to call objective c file from javascript.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
webview.delegate = self;

myButton.enabled = NO;

NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"files"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];}
```

i am using this code to call my html page successfully and i use the below code to call shouldStartLoadWithRequest method in objective c.

```
<a href="didTap://button1"><img src="cercle24px.png" /></a>
```

now i went to call new TestViewController.m file how to i call this file, i used the below code.its print the nslog correctly and give alert box also.but doesn't navigate to next file.please help me if any one know.i am waiting for your valuable reply please.

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
 {  
  NSLog(@"what");
   UIAlertView *tstAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Allowed only alphabets and numeric" delegate:self  cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
[tstAlert show];
NSString *absoluteUrl = [[request URL] absoluteString];
NSLog(@"absolute%@",absoluteUrl);
if ([absoluteUrl isEqualToString:@"didtap://button1"]) {
    NSLog(@"yes");

  TestViewController *testview=[[TestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil]; 
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:testview animated:YES];


        return NO;


  }
   NSLog(@"no");
  return YES;

  }
```

Comment: Why would it navigate to any other file? You are giving it a fake URL, not a valid file path...

Comment: when i click the button in html, i want to send sms.so only i need navigate to next file.

Comment: I don't understand your words "navigate to another file" clearly. Do you mean that pushing a viewController when user tap the button within webView? OR just in the webView, after the button is tapped, then navigate the URL (content) of the webView to a new one?

Comment: yes elf. when i tapped the button in html page. i want to open the sms box.

Comment: @vishnusivabalan Your code looks correct, you may try a new project with this code.

Comment: when i use pushViewController inside the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method it won't call.

Comment: @vishnusivabalan Does the `TestViewController` created correctly? I mean the connection between nib file and the Class file `TestViewController.m`, sorry I'm not familiar with IB..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I copy & tested your code, it works well, maybe somewhere else did wrong...
Create a new "Empty Template" Xcode project with ARC enabled, paste below into AppDelegat.m:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  WebTest
//
//  Created by Elf Sundae on 8/5/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 www.0x123.com. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface SampleViewController : UITableViewController
@end

@implementation SampleViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.title = @"Sample Controller";
}
@end

#pragma mark - 
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation WebViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        UIWebView *web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        web.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:web];
        [web loadHTMLString:@"<a href='didTap://button1'><img src='cercle24px.png' /></a>" baseURL:nil];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:nil message:@"alert message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

        NSString *urlString = request.URL.absoluteString;
        if ([urlString caseInsensitiveCompare:@"didtap://button1"] == NSOrderedSame) {

#define __use_method   3 // it could be: 1/2/3

#if (__use_method == 1)
                SampleViewController *controller = [[SampleViewController alloc] init];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
#elif (__use_method == 2)

                /* method 2 */
                SampleViewController *controller = [[SampleViewController alloc] init];
                [self.navigationController performSelector:@selector(pushViewController:animated:)
                                                withObject:controller
                                                withObject:@(YES)];
#elif (__use_method == 3)
                /* method 3 */
                __unsafe_unretained __typeof(self) _self = self;
                double delayInSeconds = 0.01;
                dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
                dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                        SampleViewController *controller = [[SampleViewController alloc] init];
                        [_self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
                });
#endif

                return NO;
        }
        return YES;
}

@end

#pragma mark - 
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:
                                          [WebViewController new]];
        return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,whether i want to add this in viewcontroller or appdelegate.

Comment: i have one doubt elf.how to pass variable from html to objevtive-c file.

Comment: for example:  See your 'didTap://button1', you can change `String` 'button1' in the html file, and handle the 'didTap://' scheme in the `-shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method, now you get the 'button1' in OjbC, clearly? In this way you communicate between objc and html.